# segment fault caused by calling virtual function of an object pointer

Tags: c++, embedded, segmentation-fault, virtual, mips

I want develop an application for a `MIPS` based `embedded device`. I am using `mipsel-elf-g++` cross compiler. I implement a simple code as bellow.

```cpp
    class A {
    public:
            virtual int getValue();
    }

    class B : public A {
    public:
            virtual int getValue();
    }

    int A::getValue() {
            return 1;
    }

    int B::getValue() {
            return 2;
    }

    int main() {

            A a1;
            B b1;
            A* a2 = &a1;
            B* b2 = &b1;

            int a_val_1 = a1.getValue();
            int b_val_1 = b1.getValue();

            int a_val_2 = a2->getValue();
            int b_val_2 = b2->getValue();

            return 0;
    }
```

`a1.getValue()` and `b1.getValue()` lines works successfully, but when each of `a2->getValue()` or `b2->getValue()` lines executed, I see `segment fault` message on the screen. I think one of the OS, compiler or library maybe are broken. I don't know how I can find the problem.

what is wrong?

Comment: You should create a minimal working example and **copy** that example into the question, rather that typing something that is similar. The code as it stands has syntax errors indicating another typo (you already corrected one), and correcting the syntax yields a valid program that should not exhibit the shown behavior which seems to indicate that there is at least one other difference is the code.

Comment: After correcting the missing ";"s on the class definitions, the code runs just fine on a MIPS system when compiled with `mips-linux-gnu-g++`.

Comment: @markgz: what is different between `mipsel-elf-g++` and `mips-linux-gnu-g++`? my embedded device OS is not linux. Can I use `mips-linux-gnu-g++` instead of `mipsel-elf-g++`?

Comment: If your system is not using Linux, you cannot use `mips-linux-gnu-g++`. However both versions of g++ are based on the same source code, so any compiler errors would appear with both tools. This suggests your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
B b1;
```

and you are assigning:

```
B* b2 = &b2;
```

It should be:

```
B* b2 = &b1;
```

Comment: True, but it shouldn't compile as it stands.

Comment: you are right, It's my mistake in my question. I edit my question.

Comment: what do u mean? do u mean this 'cannot convert ‘B**’ to ‘B*’ in initialization' ?

Comment: if in your question B* b2 = &b1 and its because u mistyped it, then there is nothing wrong in the code. It will work.

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: the problem is here. my code is not work properly. If `getValue` function defines as a none `virtual function` it works fine, but if it be `virtaul` I get `segment fault` error.

Comment: it is necessary that u make it a virtual function. read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function
And if u say that it works fine if it is defined as a non virtual function then there is something wrong.

Comment: *It is necessary that u make it a virtual function* Why? Can you explain this statement?

Comment: At this sample, there is any force and I think cleaning the issue by using another way is not solution.